# Facebook Insights API not returning store visits data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve Store Visits data from the Facebook Insights API. Based on [their documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/estimated-in-development#dev), these should be available by specifying the following parameters:

- `store_visit_actions`
- `cost_per_store_visit_actions`

When I use `store_visit_actions` as a parameter, no data is returned. I know data exists because it is displayed through their UI reporting tool.

When I use `cost_per_store_visit_actions`, I receive a 100 invalid param error:

```
cost_per_store_visit_actions is not valid for fields param.
```

These params are listed as "In Development", however, I'm retrieving other development parameters without issue. Is anyone facing the same issue or know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

this is because the metrics

```
store_visit_actions
cost_per_store_visit_actions
```

are deprecated in facebook api v11.0. You can checkout this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version11.0/